# Custom Week number from Acquistion Date of each User

Tags: filter, google-sheets, min, datediff, week-number

Is there a way to calculate Custom Week numbers that start from a user's first Transaction Date onwards? The Users (emailId) and TransDate columns may not be in a sorted condition as shown below:

e.g.

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| WkNo |  TransDate  |       emailId       |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2018-Aug-30 | moz.shea@abc.com    |
|    1 | 2018-Aug-30 | moz.shea@abc.com    |
|   10 | 2018-Nov-07 | moz.shea@abc.com    |
|    1 | 2018-Aug-09 | zabi.prado@abc.com  |
|    1 | 2018-Aug-09 | zabi.prado@abc.com  |
|    6 | 2018-Sep-20 | zabi.prado@abc.com  |
|   15 | 2018-Nov-23 | zabi.prado@abc.com  |
|   21 | 2018-Dec-31 | zabi.prado@abc.com  |
|    1 | 2018-Aug-20 | silo.whitte@abc.com |
|    5 | 2018-Sep-23 | silo.whitte@abc.com |
|    7 | 2018-10-11  | silo.whitte@abc.com |
|    7 | 2018-10-11  | silo.whitte@abc.com |
|    8 | 2018-Oct-14 | silo.whitte@abc.com |
|    9 | 2018-Oct-19 | silo.whitte@abc.com |
|    1 | 2018-Jul-01 | pablo.gucci@abc.com |
|    6 | 2018-Aug-10 | pablo.gucci@abc.com |
|   13 | 2018-Oct-03 | pablo.gucci@abc.com |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I wrote the following formula using FILTER function that then supplies the filtered dates per user to the DATEDIF function. However, i am not getting the desired result as shown above.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",1 + round(DATEDIF(min(sort(FILTER(B2:B,C2:C=C2:C),1,true)),sort(FILTER(B2:B,C2:C=C2:C),1,true),"D")/7)))
```

**EDIT:**

Formula Result:

```
1
7
7
7
8
10
10
13
13
14
16
16
16
17
19
22
27
```

Also removed SORT from above formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",1 + round(DATEDIF(min(sort(FILTER(B2:B,C2:C=C2:C),1,true)),FILTER(B2:B,C2:C=C2:C),"D")/7)))
```

Formula Result:

```
10
10
19
7
7
13
22
27
8
13
16
16
16
17
1
7
14
```

Both seem to work, but give unexpected results as MIN is evaluating to a single date `2018-Jul-01` instead of an Array of Minimum dates per user. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might face a similar challenge, here is the answer:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",ROUND((B2:B-VLOOKUP(C2:C,SORT({C2:C,B2:B},2,1),2,0))/7)+1))
```

The idea is to do a Vlookup on column C, passing it a switched and sorted range of dates in ascending order. These first dates are then deducted from the B column dates, to get the desired result ie. either days or weeks.

One can remove the +1 as i used it just to display the starting week as 1 instead of 0. So the result may differ slightly. But without +1, the result is accurate, especially if you are doing a Cohort.

```
0
0
10
0
0
6
15
21
0
5
7
7
8
9
0
6
13
```

As a check, i removed division by 7 and +1, then checked the days, which are correct.

```
0
0
69
0
0
42
106
144
0
34
52
52
55
60
0
40
94
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the MINIFS() function ?

EG with the following

Dates in cells B2:B10
Emails in Cells C2:C10

The formula in cell A2 would give the earliest date for the email address in Cell C2

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$10, $C2:$C10, "="&C2)
```

You should be able to use this in your formula to calculate the number of weeks

Comment: i am already using MIN in my formula. Where do i make the change?

Comment: MINIFS does not give me a list of minimum dates per user. Also getting error now `Function DATEDIF parameter 1 (8/30/2018) should be on or before Function DATEDIF parameter 2 (7/1/2018).`

Comment: Example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WI-DSjhexEv7J0cOSga1VBnkHgVjCQxES4SHciUgeI8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I understand you are using helper columns. What i need is a single array formula.

Comment: It is straightforward to combine the 'helper columns into one formula.

Comment: MINIFS (so does MIN) seems to return a single value instead of an array of minimum dates.

Comment: You can get the result of your stated problem by copying the formula to each row anyway, so not clear why you need to use `=ARRAYFORMULA()`

Comment: I am using an arrayformula as it robust and to avoid putting formulae in too many row cells in my sheet.